# TimeSeries: notation datavalue

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

When I use  TimeSeries, The DateObject is changed in a longer notation. For example:

```
data = {{DateObject[{2021, 01, 01}], 1}, 
        {DateObject[{2021, 01, 02}], 2}, 
        {DateObject[{2021, 01, 03}], 3}, 
        {DateObject[{2021, 01, 04}], 4}};

data1 = TimeSeries[data];

data1["DatePath"]
```

The output is:

```
{{DateObject[{2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], 1},
 {DateObject[{2021, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.`], 2},
 {DateObject[{2021, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.],3},
 {DateObject[{2021, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.], 4}}
```

Is there a way to keep the original short DateObject notation?

Comment: I don't think so. What problem does the "long" form give you?

Comment: for example, when I want to make a comparison or select statement with a DateObject which is written in hert short notation, For Example: Position[data ["DatePath"][[All, 1]], 
 DateObject[AbsoluteTime@[{2021,1,1}]]]. I use AbsoluteTime as translation.